# How I can remove more than 1 items from drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I am binding dropDownList.

I want to remove PersonList which is more than 1 item from drop down list.

This person list is already selected people I want to remove it from dropDownList data. How I can do this ?

```
dt = AppNameApi.getStaffStudList();
ddl.DataTextField = "NAME";
ddl.DataValueField = "uid_nmbr";
```

And here getting the list to remove from DropDownList

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSubjectChange.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int index = row.RowIndex;        
        Label lbluid_nmbr = row.FindControl("labeluid_nmbr") as Label;            StudStaffList.Add(Convert.ToString(gvSubjectChange.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));
        int t = StudStaffList.Count
        StudStaff = Convert.ToString(gvSubjectChange.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
        PersonList = string.Join(",", StudStaffList.ToArray());
        ViewState["PersonList"] = PersonList;
    }
}
```

code:

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "0"));
dt = (DataTable)ViewState["StaffStudList"];
ddl.DataTextField = "NAME";
ddl.DataValueField = "uid_nmbr";
ddl.DataSource = dt;      
ddl.DataBind();           
string[] Plist = (string[])ViewState["plist"];                                      
foreach (string s in Plist)
{                       
    ddl.Items.Remove(ddl.Items.FindByValue(s));  
}
```

Comment: use a `foreach(item in PersonList)`?

Comment: If the type contained in both the list is same then use Except operator otherwise refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540891/filter-linq-except-on-properties

Comment: Hi Ben , Hi tried according to you but no  success

Comment: string[] Plist = (string[])ViewState["plist"];
                                      
                    foreach (string s in Plist)
                    {                                         
                        ddl.Items.Remove(ddl.Items.FindByValue(s));
                       
                    }

Comment: methinks you need rebind your dropdown

Comment: hi Grundy rebinded gridview but no success

Comment: @pallavi, why gridview? i talk about dropdown. Can you provide more code how you use drop down and grid?

Comment: ohh sorry  i want to say rebinded dropDownList

Comment: before bind you need filter datatable as you wish

Comment: the dropdownlist within your gridview?

Comment: your `PersonList` initial as? an entity class?

Comment: you mean to say i need to bind after foreach loop. I did that also foreach (string s in Plist)
                    {                       
                        ddl.Items.Remove(ddl.Items.FindByValue(s));  

                    } ddl.databind();

Comment: @pallavi only bind with `DataSource` need `DataBind()`

Comment: what type for **uid_nmbr** field?

Comment: uid_nmbr is of  string type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need filter your data before binding, something like

```
string[] Plist = (string[])ViewState["plist"];   
var dt = from row in ((DataTable)ViewState["StaffStudList"]).AsEnumerable()
     where !Plist.Contains(row["uid_nmbr"])
     select row;

ddl.DataTextField = "NAME";
ddl.DataValueField = "uid_nmbr";
ddl.DataSource = dt;      
ddl.DataBind();
```

[AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) extension for DataTable

Comment: @ Grundy , I tried your code. Getting this error                                                  System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'NAME'.

Comment: Thanks Grundy got the result from ur code i just added select new{ Name=row["name"], uid_nmbr=row["uid_Nmbr"]}

Comment: @pallavi, possibly it work if do `ddl.DataTextField = "name"` instead of `ddl.DataTextField = "NAME"`

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `StudStaffList.ToArray()` is storing the `SelectedValue` of `DropDownList`

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSubjectChange.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int index = row.RowIndex;

            Label lbluid_nmbr = row.FindControl("labeluid_nmbr") as Label;
            StudStaffList.Add(Convert.ToString(gvSubjectChange.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));
            int t = StudStaffList.Count
            StudStaff = Convert.ToString(gvSubjectChange.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

            DropDownList ddl = row.FindCountrol("yourDropDownList") as DropDownList;

            int i = 0;
            foreach(var item in StudStaffList.ToArray()){
                ddl.Items.Remove(ddl.Items.FindByValue(StudStaffList[i]));
                i ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in you code `PersonList` is _string_ so it does not have _ID_ property

Comment: Yu Yekan,  ddl.remove(PersonList.ID); this is not working. what is ID in your code??

Comment: @Yu Yekan, I did in the same way . difference is you are removing dataTextFild. But in studstafflist its dataValue field not text so i did findByValue

Comment: ya, i don know yours is value or text