# C# FindAll Method with array of values

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, findall

I have some kind of ULR object list like below

```
List<myUrl> urls = new List<myUrl>();
```

myUrl is a class that contains 4 field and all of them string.

in this list I want to find items does not contain another given list of values

```
List<myUrl> result = urls.FindAll(
   different_from_list_of_values condition;
);
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Linq EXCEPT on properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540891/filter-linq-except-on-properties)

Comment: This has been asked multiple times on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list

Comment: try var filtered = basedEntityList.Where(i => !anotherList.Contains(i.Id)); Any or Contains methods works for this problem

Answer (score 0):

the best way should be [topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx), the idea is to override Equals method with your own logic, it have example for two fields class TwoDPoint. 
Then you just need to check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list)
instead of p2.ID == p.ID => you would rather have p2.Equals(p)