# How can I return the set diffrence between two FileInfo lists while ignoring the file extension?

Tags: c#, list, generics, ienumerable, set-difference

I have two `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` lists that I would like to compare:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*" + _ext1, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*" + _ext2, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Where _ext1 and _ext2 are diffrent file extension types. For example:

```
string _ext1 = ".jpg";
string _ext2 = ".png";
```

So `list1` will look something like:

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.jpg
file5.jpg
file6.jpg
```

and `list2` will look like:

```
file1.png
file2.png
file4.png
```

I want to find everything in list2 that is not present in list1. I have tried the following:

```
List<string> list1FileNames = list1.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName)).ToList();
List<string> list2FileNames = list2.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName)).ToList();
var setDiff = list1FileNames .Except(list2FileNames );
```

This is great and works fine and returns (notice no file extension):

```
file3
file5
file6
```

However, what I really want is to get a list of FileInfo's not just the FileName strings. I need this because I need other information like the FullFile path, ext.. so just a list of filename strings will not do the job. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540891/filter-linq-except-on-properties

Comment: See also the `ExceptBy` method from [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for speed, try this:

```
private IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetUniqueFilesWithoutExtension(IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1, IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2)
{
    var d = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var fi in list2)
    {
        d.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName));
    }

    foreach (var fi in list1)
    {
        if (!d.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName)))
        {
            yield return fi;
        }
    }
}
```

Make a hash set of file names (sans extensions) from `list2`, then iterate through `list1` and only return the items with file names (sans extensions) that don't appear in the hash set from `list2`.  The `yield return` lets you consume your results as they're discovered in a streaming fashion, instead of having to wait for the whole list to be generated, if that matters to you.

Comment: You can just use `new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(fi => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName)))` to initialize the set.

Comment: I'm aware, but I wanted to do it without LINQ.

Comment: So if I understand this right, the yeild esssentially breaks the second loop once a match is found?

Comment: Actually, I think I see what it does. It doesn't break the loop, it yeilds a return value so that your location in the loop is not lost and you don't have to start all over again. Hence making this fast! Very nice! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `yield return` streams the data out one at a time instead of waiting to return until the full list is constructed. The return object interface is just `IEnumerable<T>`, so you are free to define how the enumeration is implemented. But that's probably gold plating on my part; it only matters if you need to consume the results as they're being processed. That's not where the real speed boost comes from.

Comment: The real speed boost over LINQ comes from using `HashSet`. LINQ set comparisons such as `Any` do **linear-time lookup** on an array. Since every element in list 1 has to look at every element in list 2, comparing two lists with 10,000 items each will result in *up to 100 million comparisons!* `HashSet` circumvents that problem by letting us do constant-time lookups of list 2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*" + _ext1, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*" + _ext2, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

IEnumerable<FileInfo> filtered = list2.Where(f2 => !list1.Any(f1 =>
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f1.FullName) == Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f2.FullName)));
```

Comment: This method seems to take a very long time with my two lists, each of which contain around 9,000 items each. I am trying to figure out how to speed this up. It works fine for just 5 or 6 items, but not thousands.

Comment: @John: That's because for every item of list2 it will potentially check every single item of list1. So you got an O(n*m) algorithm here. Better to create a set of file names in list1 and check against that with `ISet<T>.Contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Where()` with `All()` for that, but it would have high time complexity:

```
var difference =  list2
                  .Where(f=>list1.All(x=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.FullName) != Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName));
```