# C# Find difference of two custom object lists based only on some properties

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

So I have the following object:

```
public class user
{
    // navigation properties
    public DateTime lastRefresh { get; set; }
    public userParent parent { get; set; }

    // query data
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public int plan { get; set; }
}
```

So I am dealing with two lists of these objects, and want to get a third list that is the difference of the two sets as follows:

```
List<user> freshUsers;
List<user> oldUsers;

//code populate lists

//get difference
List<user> uniqueUsers = freshUsers.Except(oldUsers).ToList();
```

However the users in freshUsers don't have the navigation properties that are manually added (lastRefresh and parent)  later, and even if they did, the lastRefresh wouldn't match the otherwise same user in oldUsers.

So what I need here is a way to get the difference between the lists based only off of their data properties (id, created_at, plan), and was wondering the best way to do that. Should I create a custom equality to do it with, or is there some clever way of using LINQ to compare only the 3 values that are appropriate?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the users in freshUsers don't have the navigation properties"*? Both lists are of the same type. It's not possible for some objects of a type to not have the same properties as other objects of the same type, is it?

Comment: Also, the sample you wrote only gives the **fresh** users who aren't in old users, but not any of the old users that aren't in fresh users. Is that what you want? (your problem statement says you want the differences, which would include the latter group)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540891/filter-linq-except-on-properties, especially some of the extension methods.

Comment: @RufusL by "the users in freshUsers don't have the navigation properties" you are correct, by "don't have" I just mean they were null/not set so I wouldn't expect them to match anything. And you're also correct in saying I'm not getting the true difference, Except is the functionality I want (getting all the fresh users but making sure there's no overlap).

Comment: @NetMage thanks, that's a very useful set of answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your user class, implement the interface `IEquatable<user>`. This creates a method to compare one user object to another. Inside this method you need to define when two objects are the same (by comparing properties).

Or... create another class which has the task to compare two users. You need to implement `IEqualityComparer<user>`. Implementing this interface will provide a method to compare two user-objects. Now you can call `Except` with an instance of this comparer as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to override the `Equals` method (along with `GetHashCode`). Then you can use the `System.Linq` extension methods to get what you want:

```
public class user
{
    // navigation properties
    public DateTime lastRefresh { get; set; }
    public userParent parent { get; set; }

    // query data
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public int plan { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as user;
        return Equals(other);
    }

    protected bool Equals(user other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return string.Equals(id, other.id) && 
            created_at.Equals(other.created_at) && 
            plan == other.plan;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = id?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ created_at.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ plan;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can get what you want using your `Linq` code, and the items will be compared using your `Equals` override code:

```
//get difference
List<user> uniqueUsers = freshUsers.Except(oldUsers).ToList();
```

Comment: In general, when overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, the class values should also be made read-only so as to not break dictionaries and hash tables which rely on the hash code never changing.

Comment: @Enigmativity I had not thought about that. But I'm confused how that works when `Equals` uses fields that aren't read-only in many cases. Would you just use fewer fields for `GetHashCode`? In this case, perhaps `id` and `created_at` could be read-only (and therefore set via a constructor, I guess). What would you do?

Comment: You could make `GetHashCode` return `0` for every value and it would work - but it'd be less efficient in hash tables. So, yes, you can just use those fields that are immutable, but it would be better to make them all immutable.