# Exclude LINQ results from one query in another LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have two linq queries, querying two different entities. One entity contains all the warehouses, and another contains warehouses I don't need.

I use this query to get all the warehouses I don't need:

```
var sysproWarehouses = from i in sysproSession.Query<InvWarehouse>()
                            group i by i.Warehouse
                            into g
                            select new
                            {
                                g.Key 
                            };
```

This is the query where I want to get all the warehouses I do need:

```
var stockEvaluation = from ib in mapicsSession.Query<ItemBalance>()
                                  where //I guess it needs to be done here
                                  orderby w.Description
                                  group ib by w.Description
                                  into g
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Warehouse = g.Key,
                                  };
```

Basically I just need to exclude the first query results from the second query. I apologise if this is a simple question, but I am a beginner so... Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the `Except` function. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: where !sysproWarehouses.Any(your test here) or what cramopy said

Comment: Also you can add a `where` clause to your existing query and in this where check for `!sysproWarehouses.Contains()` function.

Comment: Additional information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540891/filter-linq-except-on-properties

Comment: Looks like you want to perform difference on the two sets. Have a look at Except function provided by EF. Following link contains a good enough explanation: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/linq-expect-intersect-and-union-method-operator-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
var sysproWarehouses = from i in sysproSession.Query<InvWarehouse>()
                            group i by i.Warehouse
                            into g
                            select new
                            {
                                g.Key 
                            };

var stockEvaluation = from ib in mapicsSession.Query<ItemBalance>()
                        orderby w.Description
                        group ib by w.Description
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            g.Key,
                        };
```

Now, exclude the sysproWarehouses list items from stockEvaluation list:

```
var result = stockEvaluation.Except(sysproWarehouses);
```

**Note:-** result contains the excluded items

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need an `Except`, but *after* the call to `Select`, as your two lists come from different tables. Something like this:

```
var stockEvaluation = (from ib in mapicsSession.Query<ItemBalance>()
                      orderby w.Description
                      group ib by w.Description
                      into g
                      select new
                      {
                          g.Key,
                      }).Except(sysproWarehouses);
```

Be aware that I also changed the only member within your anonymous type to match the type from your first query.

Comment: Will except be translated to SQL?

Comment: I get the following error @HimBromBeere: `'string' does not contain a definition for and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ method `Except()`
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Without showing how to use this, your answer - if at all - isn´t very helpfull.